# How to connect to specific porttype in WFC via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, wcf

I was able to connect to my WCF Web service via PowerShell `New-WebServiceProxy`. My Web Service contains 3 porttypes. My problem is - I can't call any other methods than those in first porttype.

I'm connecting to WebService using following command:

```
$ws = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri "http://server/myService.svc?wsdl"
```

I can create object of any class from WebService:

```
$obj = New-Object($ws.GetType().NameSpace + ".ClassName")
```

I can call methods from first porttype in wsdl:

```
$result = $ws.KontrahentDodaj($obj)
```

But I can't call method from any other porttype:

```
$result2 = $ws.FakturyLista($otherObject)
```

> Error - Method invocation failed because [] does not contain a method named 'FakturyLista'.

Here's fragment of my wsdl:

```
<wsdl:portType name="IKontrahentService">
  <wsdl:operation name="KontrahentDodaj">
      <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IKontrahentService/KontrahentDodaj" message="tns:IKontrahentService_KontrahentDodaj_InputMessage"/>
      <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IKontrahentService/KontrahentDodajResponse" message="tns:IKontrahentService_KontrahentDodaj_OutputMessage"/>
  </wsdl:operation>
  <wsdl:operation name="KontrahentZmien">
    <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IKontrahentService/KontrahentZmien" message="tns:IKontrahentService_KontrahentZmien_InputMessage"/>
    <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IKontrahentService/KontrahentZmienResponse" message="tns:IKontrahentService_KontrahentZmien_OutputMessage"/>
  </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:portType name="IFakturaService">
  <wsdl:operation name="FakturaDodaj">
    <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IFakturaService/FakturaDodaj" message="tns:IFakturaService_FakturaDodaj_InputMessage"/>
    <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IFakturaService/FakturaDodajResponse" message="tns:IFakturaService_FakturaDodaj_OutputMessage"/>
  </wsdl:operation>
  <wsdl:operation name="FakturyLista">
    <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IFakturaService/FakturyLista" message="tns:IFakturaService_FakturyLista_InputMessage"/>
    <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IFakturaService/FakturyListaResponse" message="tns:IFakturaService_FakturyLista_OutputMessage"/>
  </wsdl:operation>
  <wsdl:operation name="ZalacznikiDoFakturyLista">
    <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IFakturaService/ZalacznikiDoFakturyLista" message="tns:IFakturaService_ZalacznikiDoFakturyLista_InputMessage"/>
    <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IFakturaService/ZalacznikiDoFakturyListaResponse" message="tns:IFakturaService_ZalacznikiDoFakturyLista_OutputMessage"/>
  </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
```

EDIT:
After using command `$ws | gm -MemberType Method` I've got following result:

```
    TypeName: Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy1SERVICENAME_svc.BasicHttpBinding_IKontrahentService
Name                      MemberType Definition                                                                        
----                      ---------- ----------                                                                        
Abort                     Method     void Abort()                                                                      
BeginKontrahentDodaj      Method     System.IAsyncResult BeginKontrahentDodaj(Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebse...
BeginKontrahentZmien      Method     System.IAsyncResult BeginKontrahentZmien(Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebse...
CancelAsync               Method     void CancelAsync(System.Object userState)                                         
CreateObjRef              Method     System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjRef CreateObjRef(type requestedType)                   
Discover                  Method     void Discover()                                                                   
Dispose                   Method     void Dispose(), void IDisposable.Dispose()                                        
EndKontrahentDodaj        Method     Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceP...
EndKontrahentZmien        Method     Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceP...
Equals                    Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)                                                    
GetHashCode               Method     int GetHashCode()                                                                 
GetLifetimeService        Method     System.Object GetLifetimeService()                                                
GetType                   Method     type GetType()                                                                    
InitializeLifetimeService Method     System.Object InitializeLifetimeService()                                         
KontrahentDodaj           Method     Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceP...
KontrahentDodajAsync      Method     void KontrahentDodajAsync(Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.Auto...
KontrahentZmien           Method     Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceP...
KontrahentZmienAsync      Method     void KontrahentZmienAsync(Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.Auto...
ToString                  Method     string ToString()
```

Comment: Could you get those methods information by the following command?
$ws | Get-Member -MemberType method
Reference.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-webserviceproxy?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: Hi Abraham. I've edited my post and included results from this command.

Comment: So where is FskturyLista method?  How do you define the operation and expose the operation on the server end?

Comment: On my end, I created the service by using wcf basichttpbinding. And the auto-generated proxy class contains all method I have.